# Using subprocess.call with variables

Tags: python, subprocess, 7zip

I'm creating a routine which I will setup as a scheduled task in Windows to automatically take a copy of our database and post it to a Web Server for downloads by our customers.

I've gotten everything working using static strings in the arguments for the subprocess call which uses 7-zip to create a self-extracting archive. However, when I tried to make the logic a little more agnostic by using os.path.join and os.path.dirname to dynamically determine argument values for the subprocess.call function, things stopped working.

I can't figure out what's wrong because when I run it in the cmd console providing static strings as the arguments it works fine. 
Additionally, it works fine through Python when I use static strings.
It's only when I introduce the variables and functions into the arguments to try and dynamically determine the argument values and no error codes or messages are provided.

```
# Get the Database location
localGDB = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), r"Resources\MyDatabase.gdb")

# Wrap the local File Geodatabase into a self-extracting exe
print "Wrapping local database..."
try:
    subprocess.Popen([str(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), r"Resources\7z\7-Zip64\7z.exe")),
                    "a",
                    "-sfx",
                    str(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "MyDatabase.exe")),
                    str(localGDB)])
except Exception as e:
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "An error occured while wrapping the database." + e.message, "ERROR", 0 | 0x10)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: You should be more strict about the Exception type that you are allowing.

Comment: I would if I could get any idea of what kind of exception is occuring.

Comment: When I am in that situation I remove the try except block. Then if an exception is raised it tells me the type.

Comment: Also, as a debugging measure I would print all the dynamically constructed paths and commands.

Comment: Laying out your directories relative to the script file's directory seems counter to sanity (though if you are using Windows, yours is probably long gone anyway). A more sustainable solution would be to simply require the `7z` binary to be in the user's `PATH`, and perhaps simply to expect the user to run the script in the directory where they want the output.

Comment: @triplee: Please read the section of the post which describes the purpose of this script. This script is not intended to be executed by a user. Also, laying out the directories and resources relative to the location of the source makes perfect sense when you want your solution to be capable of operating from any directory. In doing so, you ensure that as long as the entire directory containing all dependencies is kept together and the structure remains unchanged, the script works. This is a standard practice when building a solution.

Comment: The `traceback` module has functions to help figure out execptions. When you post your message box you could get a string describing the exception from `traceback.print_exc()`.

Comment: Your example code doesn't wait for the `Popen` process to complete. I assume you hit the exception so it doesn't matter.... but do wait in your real code.

Comment: How about checking paths (e.g. `assert os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), r"Resources\7z\7-Zip64\7z.exe"))`) before the call?

Answer (score 2):

If on windows, I would suggest running `subprocess.check_output()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone. After taking tdelaney's advice to check the paths, I found that the 7zip path was incorrect.